How can I solve "str" object?
I was practicing about indexes and also while cycle when I came across such a problem.
What is the solution??
name = "aurrora"
index = 0
while index \< len(name) :
letter = name(index)
print(letter)
index = index+1


What problem? What solution?

Please start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Don't know the error you are facing but couple of errors you must be having are:

while \< len(name) it should have given SyntaxError

letter = name(index) it should have given TypeError as index is accessed using [] brackets not (), modified code below should work.
name = "aurrora"
index = 0
while index < len(name):
      letter = name[index]  # Use square brackets to access by index
      print(letter)
      index = index + 1



